# How to block navigation/tabbar controller for 5 sec?

Tags: iphone, uiview, timer, hud

I have ATMhud. I' m showing hud with progress bar. I want to download actualization then.

But user can back to previous view and stop actualization.

I' m tried push "push black view", but i only cover current view without navigation/tabar.

How i can block clicking everything, before actualization finish?

Comment: I used self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you want to prevent user to interact with your view till your loading process is finished. You can set Views userInteractionEnabled property for that.

When you go for loading show at that moment set

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = NO`

and after when your process is finished

`self.view.userInteractionEnabled = YES`

so this way you can prevent user to interact anywhere on your view while process is undergoing.

Hope it helps.